# Having a problem redirecting with the correct pk value in django

Tags: django

So, I am having trouble redirecting using `other_user` pk. I can't figure out to pass that pk in. I am either passing request.user pk, or I am getting a 'local variable 'other_user' referenced before assignment' error. I can pass `other_user` into my template, but , I don't how to combine the href link WITH the button to submit the form. I wonder if that's even possible? I did try doing it via the redirect method with `other_user.id`, but I can't. So, basically I am getting the other_user when I query for it, but I don't know how to pass it to my redirect so it take my user where it needs to go. How would I go about solving this problem?

```
views.py/message

def message (request, profile_id):



if request.method == 'POST':



    form = MessageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()


        return redirect('dating_app:messages')
else:
    conversation, created = Conversation.objects.filter(members = request.user).filter(members= profile_id).get_or_create()

    other_user = conversation.members.filter(id=profile_id).get()

    form = MessageForm({'sender': request.user, 'conversation': conversation})

    context = {'form' : form, 'other_user': other_user }

    return render(request, 'dating_app/message.html', context)
```

**message.html**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'dating_app:message' user.id %}" class="form">


    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    {% buttons %}
        <button name="submit">login</button>
    {% endbuttons %}

    <a href="{% url 'dating_app:messages' other_user.id %}">Start messaging </a>

    <input type="hidden" name="next"
        value="{% url 'dating_app:messages' other_user.id %}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so it was a simple fix actually. I just needed to pass in `other_user.id` into my action section of my form where as before I was passing in `user.id` which was taking in my `request.user` pk. However, I was able to get `other_user.id` from my `other_user` query in my view. And I was already passing `'other_user' : other_user` in my template anyways, so I simply just needed to pass it into my action url. I also cleaned up my form a little.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'dating_app:message' **other_user.id** %}" class="form">


    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    {% buttons %}
        <button name="submit">Send Message</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better you add `urls.py` with your question. I've assume that you have path defined like this.

```
app_name = "dating_app"
urlpatterns = [
    path("message/<pk>/", views.message, name="messages")
]
```

Now you can use `reverse` with an argument like this.

```
return redirect(reverse("dating_app:messages", profile_id))
```

Comment: profile_id hasn't worked, when I had it with just redirect, it passes request.user pk. And now, with adding reverse as you suggested, it's giving m this error 'Exception Value: 
The included URLconf '1' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.'

Comment: And yes, my urls.py is exactly that